# Data Recognize and Parse

Tags: asp.net, json, hashmap

Could you help me to find the type of below data and how can I parse this in asp.net for a web application.

The data is coming from Azure partner center

### Customer details

```
Id: gsdvghvsdhhsd
CommerceId: sdbvsdbvbsdnsbd
CompanyProfile:
    TenantId: dgsdgsffwtxx7781228
    Domain: cdsdftw.gsdhasja.com
    CompanyName: SOFTDSRD Tnsja Ltd
    Links:
        Self:
            Uri: /customers/sbandbns-273-hs-23hd/profiles/company
            Method: GET
            Headers:
    Attributes:
        ObjectType: CustomerCompanyProfile
BillingProfile:
    Id: sgdhwg-72384gbds-sdhwe98-
    FirstName: Test
    LastName: Test
    Email: Test@test.com
    Culture: en-US
    Language: en
    CompanyName: SOFTDSRD Tnsja Ltd
    DefaultAddress:
        Country: IN
        City: TestCity
        State: Test State
        AddressLine1: dsbhfhsh23u bsdbjsnd90
        AddressLine2: Plot No-7, TestCity,Test State
        PostalCode: 374864
        FirstName: Test
        LastName: Test
        PhoneNumber: cgsdjhghfshdsn
    Links:
        Self:
            Uri: /customers/sbandbns-273-hs-23hd/profiles/profiles/billing
            Method: GET
            Headers:
    Attributes:
        Etag: -856840410935075945
        ObjectType: CustomerBillingProfile
RelationshipToPartner: Reseller
AllowDelegatedAccess: True
Links:
    Self:
        Uri: /customers/8c249b3a-9f2d-4f39-94a2-2ae9ab09dac5
        Method: GET
        Headers:
Attributes:
```

### ObjectType: Customer

Comment: This is the data related to Billing details and you can easily parse this data from JSON to entity in asp.net. You want to display this data on your web page?

Comment: Thank @Aman , I am very new to dot net technology. Yes, I need to display this on our web page.

Comment: So can you please tell how this data is coming from Azure and in which format you want to display on web page.